# Moving to the UK with my EU-citizen husband shortly after marrying

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, marriage, indian-citizens

I am an Indian working in Germany, Düsseldorf for the last 2 years.

I got married last week and my husband, who is a Greek citizen, lives and works in London. We got married in Denmark.

I am trying to relocate to London, where I am stuck with lot of questions regarding visa.

1. What is the process of changing my marital status in Dusseldorf.
2. Do I need any extra visa to travel to London or marrying an European automatically give me the right to go to London?
3. Do I need any other visa to work in London?

Comment: It's best to ask about one issue at a time, like relocating to the UK. Marital status in Düsseldorf is a distinct question. Do you really need to do anything about that if you intend to relocate anyway?

Comment: Each of these questions requires quite a bit of detail. As we're in beta, still, we try to keep it to one question per post. Please have a read of the [help] and edit your question, and maybe ask them separately, so that those who know can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMayo I think question 2/3 are completely fine and can be answered succinctly and comprehensively. Question 1 should just be split.

Answer (score 2):

Being married to an EU citizen gives you the right to join him in London and work there but you still need some paperwork. The difference is that it's supposed to be a formality, cheaper and quicker than a regular work or spouse visa, and not at the discretion of the authorities.

Specifically, what you need is an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview). Once you have it and enter the UK, you do not need any other visa to work in London. You could however apply for a [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/overview) to prove your right to stay and work in the UK and help you travel in and out of the country in the future.

Unfortunately, while you do have a strong right to join your husband, the UK still makes it more difficult that it should to effectively use that right. I don't have any statistics but I have heard about some very long delays (in 2008, up to 10-12 months, hopefully it's better now) and [hard to justify refusals](https://eumovement.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/is-uk-handling-of-eea-family-permit-visas-still-a-problem/). Officially, visas for members of the family of an EU citizen [should be given priority](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eea-family-permits-eun02/eea-family-permit-eun02) and should usually be issued quickly time but there are no guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for the information provided and it is really helpful, a further question , do you have any idea how many days it would take to get the EEA family permit?

Comment: @sahitya I added a few details about that.